# nixos: overlays calling overlays

Tags: overlay, nix, nixos

I have an overlay defined in nix, in my ~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/tmft.nix, that looks like this:

```
self: super: {
  tfmt = import ../dists/tfmt/default.nix {};
}
```

That's fine, I can install it fine.  It's a haskell package, and I want to install it as part of my ghc install.  So I have another overlay, in myHaskellEnv.nix, that looks like this:

```
self: super: {
  myHaskellEnv = super.haskellPackages.ghcWithHoogle
                   (haskellPackages: with haskellPackages;
                   [ tfmt ]);
}
```

Only, that complains that it can't see tfmt (`error: undefined variable 'tfmt'`).

I can work around this by importing the package directly:

```
let tfmt = import ../dists/tfmt/default.nix {};
 in self: super: {
  myHaskellEnv = super.haskellPackages.ghcWithHoogle
                   (haskellPackages: with haskellPackages;
                   [ tfmt ]);
}
```

but that defeats the reuse.

How can I use the one overlay from another?  I tried referring to super.tfmt, but that shows the same issue.

Comment: I have now discovered that it works in some other cases - it looks suspiciously like there is an evaluation-order thing going on here, such that you can refer to things that are defined in overlays lexically preceding the one trying to make the reference.  Can anybody confirm/deny that, and if it's true, are there common patterns to deal with that?  Renaming things according to evaluation order doesn't seem particularly scalable.

Comment: No, it's not as simple as that - I tried renaming tfmt.nix to 00-tfmt.nix, to force it earlier in the lexical order; to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

An overlay is just a function from `self` and `super` to an attribute set (usually of packages). The same scoping rules apply as in any Nix function definition. So when you want to use something from a previous overlay, it isn't magically in scope; you have to get it from `self` or `super` which represent the final package set and definition from earlier overlays only.

By changing `[ tfmt ]` to `[ self.tfmt ]` you should be able to insert the final definition of `tfmt` - as it may be overridden in subsequent overlays. Alternatively, you could get `tfmt` from `super`, which is not recommended because it is less flexible, but sometimes you need `super` to avoid creating cyclic definitions that result in infinite recursions during evaluation.

---

When writing overlays, you should avoid re-importing Nixpkgs, directly or indirectly. This is important because `<nixpkgs>` may be the wrong version of Nixpkgs for someone's use and if you do get it right, you will re-evaluate the Nixpkgs fixpoint, which takes time, you will lose any configuration that was in the original Nixpkgs, like `config` and `overlays` and cross compilations arguments.

Instead, you should use the `self` and `super` attributes. In particular, `super.callPackage` comes in handy, but for Haskell packages you'd best override a haskell package set, extending it with your own packages, for consistency.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/nix-community/todomvc-nix/blob/f3c7c35b00dc0c5897a08531e5902e09110aeb1a/nix/all-packages.nix#L31) of this.

Also, I recommend keeping your number of overlays to the bare minimum. Only split them if it makes sense from a software distribution perspective - that's what they were intended for.